# how to restrict user access: only connect and exec function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Please advice how to restrict user access to mssql: just connect and execute only specific list of functions or stored procedures. The problem is that default 'public' role is giving more rights than needed - list databases, get user list etc.
How to close as much as possile (deny all) and after that open only what is allowed?

Real situation is the following: partner site asked not to get data through xml webservice but have direct connection to mssql and I am going to make a table function for them or stored procedure with parameters, but want to hide everything what is going on inside server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deny them permissions they will not need. For instance, you can [`DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182763%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) so that they cannot see other databases on the server. There are lots of options available through the DENY facility (so many that they have separate pages for those that apply at the server level, and those that apply at the [database level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177518%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)).

---

Just:

```
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE to <user> --Run in master
```

and

```
DENY VIEW DEFINTION to <user> -- run in the database you've given them connect permission
```

should be sufficient that they cannot see anything, or select from any tables. Then you just need to explicitly grant them the permissions you want them to have.

Comment: when I check `sp_helprotect null,'public'` - I whish to close all available actions, is it right way to set up restrictions? Or other easy way available when I can just deny all and permit exact what I need?